# How can I update Cassandra table with only primary key and static columns?

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax

I am using Cassandra 3.9 and DataStax C++ driver 2.6.  I have created a table that has only a primary key and static columns.  I am able to insert data into the table, but I am not able to update the table and I don't know why.  As an example, I created the table `t` that is defined here:

`[Cassandra Table with primary key and static column][1]`

Then I successfully inserted data into the table with the following CQL insert command:

`"insert into t (k, s, i) VALUES('George', 'Hello', 2);"`

Then, `"select * from t;"` results in the following:

```
    k      | i | s
    -------+---+-------
    George | 2 | Hello
```

However, if I then try to update the table using the following command:

`"UPDATE t set s = "World"  where k = "George";"`

I get the following error:

> SyntaxException: line 1:26 no viable alternative at input 'where' (UPDATE t set s = ["Worl]d"  where...)

Does anyone know how to update a table with only static columns and a primary key (i.e. partition key + cluster key)?

Answer (score 2):

**Enclose string with single quote**

Example :

```
UPDATE t set s = 'World' where k = 'George';
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted